# What is the inversion of an offset nephroid across the unit circle?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

More specifically, if I have the nephroid $\left(\left(x+.5\right)^{2}+y^{2}-4a^{2}\right)^{3}=108a^{4}y^{2}$:

1. What is its polar representation?
2. What is its inversion across the unit circle, in cartesian and polar?
3. If it's "ugly", is there any scaling of the nephroid which gives a "nice" inversion?

Comment: Could you say which context has given you an interest towards this curve, and its inversion (btw, a transformation I love) ?

Comment: I imagine that you have had a look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephroid#Inversion_of_a_nephroid) on the "standard" nephroid and its inverse. Shifting a curve has in general disastrous consequences on its polar representation therefore on its inverse...

Comment: I saw that a cardioid had a very nice inverse when its cusp was placed at the origin, so wondered what the inversion would be with a nephroid. The inversion with a centered nephroid is very... uninteresting, and so I wondered if something could be gotten from the offset version. @JeanMarie